# Invalid memory reference and pointer problem

Tags: c

The question is to receive a new number and sort all in descending order.I want to combine old with new number ,put them to a new array.and then sort them.I took a long time to handle with it but failed.SOS! What is the problem?

```
 int* fun(int* a, int num){
     int pa[7];
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
         pa[i]=a[i];
     }
     pa[6]=num;
     swap(pa,7);
    return pa;
 }
 void swap(int *pa,int n)
{
    int i,j,t;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(*(pa+i)>*(pa+j))
              {
                t=*(pa+i);
                *(pa+i)=*(pa+j);
                *(pa+j)=t;
              }
        }
    }
}
int main(){
  int a[7]={86,89,23,34,11,87};
  int num;
  scanf("%d",&num);
  int *pa=fun(a,num);
  for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
  printf("%d ",*(pa+i));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fun()` returns a pointer to (the first element of) an array that is local to that function, so has automatic storage duration.   That means, as far as your program is concerned, the array ceases to exist when the function returns.   Accessing elements of the array after that (via `*(pa + i)`) therefore gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: As this is tagged [C++] use `std::vector` and `std::sort`.  The above code is pure `C` and if a `C++` answer is not appropriate please remove the [C++] tag.

Answer (score 0):

The **pa** in your fun() is a local variable to it. This means that anything concerned with pa is freed when your function returns. If you want to return a newly formed array, use dynamic memory allocation with the aid of malloc() or calloc() functions and not simply an array you create and pass a reference of.

Sometimes, you may get the contents you expect from such a return, but it is not certain as the memory you are returning is now free to be reused and can be overwritten. The contents of the pa in fun() after returning are not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Function variables are created in the stack. After the execution of the function ends, all of its variables are "removed" from stack. So you can't access them outside the function. For example,

```
int* f(){
  int x = 5;
  int* a = &x;
  return a;
}
```

This function will return the address of `x` but that address will be an invalid address because the variables `x`, `a` cease to exist after the execution of the function ends.
***How to get around it?***
Store the data in the heap. The stack is cleared after the execution of the function ends but heap is not cleared, so you can store something in the heap and access it later from anywhere anytime.

```
int* fun(){
  int*x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); // allocates 4 byte memory in the heap.
  *x=5;
  return x;
}

int main(){
  int* check = fun();
  printf("Value: %d\n",*check);

}
```